# Magento 2.3 Module 'Magento_GoogleShoppingAds': Upgrading data... takes much time

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation, google-shopping

While upgrading Magento from Magento 2.2 to Magento 2.3 or Installing Magento 2.3.4 version, Module name `Magento_GoogleShoppingAds` taking much time to install.

Is this expected?

Does any one faced this issue? Any tip to remove module from installation?

Comment: please if the solution below worked for you , mark it as correct answer

Comment: @AhmedChouihi i used `php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:upgrade` that works well.

Answer (score 2):

Try editing php.ini with 
`sudo nano /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini`
and change

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M
```

Then restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`
and refresh the browser

I had to wait a while but finally it worked

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I type sudo service httpd restart (As I use Fedora 30) , I got this error : Failed to start the Apache HTTP Server